# Relationship between the four fundamental sub spaces

Tags: linear-algebra

I am self studying linear algebra from Gilbert strang. I can understand the dimensions of the four subspaces but I am having trouble understanding the four subspaces from the perspective of linear transformations between them . In the book it says every matrix multiplication Ax=b,  takes the row space of the matrix A to its column space . I just don't see how it is happening? - Intuitive explanations will help a lot. Thanks in advance

Comment: What four "fundamental spaces"? It'e be a good idea if you define your stuff as not everybody knows Strang's book. And try to focus your question and not make it too general.

Comment: I would be glad if some one could explain the dynamics of linear transformations that occur between these spaces.!!

Comment: what does it mean to understand the four subspace? do you have a question you are unable to answer?

Comment: It's hard to guess what you mean by "dynamics of lin. transf. between those spaces". Strang's definitions are not everybody's cup of tea (and not mine, either) and I think they might make pretty simple things messy and cumbersome.

Comment: Yea , In the book it says that every vector b in the column space comes from exactly a single  vector x in the row space. It goes on to say that the row space along with the null space acts like the domain and that the column space is like the range along with the left null space. I just don't see this connection intuitively.

Comment: @jaigowtham It cannot be the book says what you say it does as it is blatantly false **unless** it is *also* given the matrix (or lin. trans.) is injective ($\iff$  its kernel is zero). For the other things read my answer.

Comment: @timbuc The book is right. My interpretation is wrong I guess. My bad . This stuff is new to me,  thanks a lot for your answer. It helped :-)

Answer (score 1):

You are confused when you say "takes the row space of the matrix $A$ to its column space". Viewing the row space as a subspace of the space $V$ that $A$ operates upon (in the way the the kernel is)  is not a very productive point of view. (Though if you limit your interest to the cases where $V=\Bbb R^n$, the point of view is *possible* since a row is specified by $n$ numbers.) Each row of $A$ corresponds to an *expression* that computes for every $v\in V$ one coordinate of $A\cdot v$; it gives a *linear form* on$~V$. These are real-valued functions defined on $V$, each of which (if it is a nonzero function) takes the value$~0$ on a subspace of dimension$~n-1$.

For instance taking
$$ A=\begin{pmatrix} 3&1&-2\\0&-2&1\end{pmatrix}
\quad\text{for which}\quad
A\cdot\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\\z\end{pmatrix}
 = \begin{pmatrix} 3x+1y-2z\\0x-2y+1z\end{pmatrix}
$$
the first row of $A$ corresponds to the expression $3x+1y-2z$, which is not a vector in $\Bbb R^3$, but a (linear) function on $\Bbb R^3$ that for any $v=(x,y,z)\in\Bbb R^3$ gives the first coordinate of $A\cdot v$. It takes the value $0$ on a *plane* (dimension$~2$) in $\Bbb R^3$, which can be described as the span of (for instance) the vectors $(1,-3,0)$ and $(0,2,1)$.

So what is mapped to the column (image) space is not the row space, but *all of $V$*. However some elements of $V$ are mapped to the zero vector, and these form the kernel (right null space). It is the intersection of the subspaces where the linear forms for each of the rows of $A$ take the value$~0$.

In the example the intersection of the mentioned plane and the plane where the second coordinate of $A\cdot v$ (given by the second row of $A$) is $0$, gives a line (dimension$~1$), which is spanned by $(1,1,2)$. It is the kernel of$~A$. Note that taking any linear combination of the rows of $A$ gives a linear function that will also by $0$ on the kernel of $A$. Thus the row space of $A$ can be thought of as a *space of linear functions* that all vanish everywhere on the line that is the kernel of$~A$ (and *each* of the functions vanishes elsewhere too, but not at the same vectors for all of them). By contrast viewing the rows $(3,1,-2)$ and $(0,-2,1)$ of $A$ as vectors in $\Bbb R^3$ is not useful; there is nothing special about what $A$ does with those vectors (or linear combinations of them).

Comment: Each row of A corresponds to an expression that computes for every v∈V one coordinate of A⋅v; it gives a linear form on V. These are real-valued functions defined on V, each of which (if it is a nonzero function) takes the value 0 on a subspace of dimension n−1. So what is mapped to the column (image) space is not the row space, but all of V. - I find all this informative but difficult to process for an amateur like me. CAN YOU PLEASE ELABORATE AND EXPLAIN in SIMPLER WORDS OR WITH AN EXAMPLE . Thanks in advance

Comment: @jaigowtham Example given. If you find my words too difficult, you could maybe point out which ones are causing you difficulty.

Comment: I am having difficulty understandin 1)what exactly is mapped to the column space 2) what does it mean when the expression A.v takes the value zero in the plane R^2 with in the space of dimension R^3.

Answer (score 0):

In short: for $\;n\times m\;$ matrix $\;A\;$ over some field $\;\Bbb F\;$ , we have that

1) The number of linearly independent rows, when seen as vectors in the space $\;\Bbb F^m\;$, is the dimension of its rows space, which equals the dimension of its columns space ( when seen as vectors in $\;\Bbb F^n\;$), and this is the dimension of the image of $\;A\;$ (or of the linear transformation this matrix represents wrt some basis. from now on, we mix both ideas, lin. trans. and matrix, on purpose)

2) By the dimension's theorem, which states that $\;\dim\ker A+\dim\text{Im}\,A=m\;$, we have thus that $\;\dim\ker A=m-\dim\ker A\;$ , so by the above we have that the dimension of the kernel equals the domain space's dimension ($\;m\;$, in this case) *minus* the row (or column) dimension or rank.

3) Also, by the above, a basis for the column space of $\;A\;$ is a basis for Im$\;A\;$, and thus for any $\;b\in\Bbb F^n\;$ for which there exists $\,x\in\Bbb F^m\;$ s.t. $\;Ax=b\;$ we get that $\;b\in\text{Span}\{\text{colums of}\;A\}\;$ .